# Batch remove parentheses and square brackets from file name

Tags: windows

I would like to know how to remove parentheses and square brackets and what's inside of them in a list of files' names, using a .bat file

For example:

[Tag]File (1).mkv

to

File.mkv

Comment: I suppose the length of what's between parentheses or brackets, and outside them, is variable, right? Have you tried something so far? You may have some chances trying the `for` command, but I'm not sure. I've used it for some renamings but with constant lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your issue can be found in [syntax-replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). The first thing you want to do is have the batch file turn your file name into a variable. From there, you can use syntax-replacement with the `set=` to replace/remove parts of the variable.

The script bellow will remove `[square brackets]` and the contents inside them, and `(parentheses)` and the contents inside them.

Please keep in mind that this script bellow in an example to demonstrate *syntax-replacement*. It will not check/test (if) somethings in-front or behind. It expects you to have it formatted as **[Tag]Name(#).ex** - Change it to your needs.

```
@echo off
@setlocal

::Input your file location bellow.
call :edit "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\[TAG]Hello(1).jpg"
goto :EOF

:edit

::Define file as variable
set file=%~1
set start=%~1

::Define file extension as variable
set ext=%file:*.=%

::Remove right square bracket and everything before it
set square=%file:*]=%

::Remove everything after left parentheses
set efile=%square%
set endbit=%efile:*(=%
call set result=%%efile:%endbit%=%%

::Remove left parentheses
set final=%result:(=%

::Add file extension and rename
ren %start% "%final%.%ext%"

exit
```